# Efficiently search a string serialized python dict stored in Redis

Tags: python-2.7, redis, twisted

I'm using python **Twisted** server with **Redis** as a persistent storage medium. I'm using the **txredis** library to make calls to Redis from Twisted.
Now, suppose I have multiple python dicts like:

```
{"ID" : 10}
{"ID" : 11}
{"ID" : 12}
{"ID" : 13}
```

I first convert them to JSON strings using json.dumps() and store them in a Redis list using the RPUSH command.

Now, my problem is, I need to search this list (stored in Redis) for a specific ID number and determine its index in the list. I believe I could write a loop, starting from index zero, retrieve each item of the list from Redis, convert it to dict using json.loads() and check the ID. But I feel that it would be very inefficient (making so many calls to Redis). Is there any other efficient way to do this task? Or if someone can suggest a new format I can use to store a list of dicts in Redis and be able to search those dicts.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep an auxiliary hash in Redis that just contains ID_number -> index in dict, then you can just reference that?

If that's no good for whatever reason (i.e. you don't want to use up the extra space), you can write a short [lua script](https://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/) that will [deserialize your json and search it for whatever you need](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bpo/044fed4c53fc61a1a0a0/raw/json-get.lua) server-side, so you don't have to pass the entire json blob back.